# How do I compare a 2 Dimensional Array to itself to get unique values?

Tags: php, arrays, email, multidimensional-array, unique

My issue is that I am grabbing some users emails out of a 2 D array of objects but without getting duplicates or not grabbing them. They each need an email sent to them but not more than 1.

My current Code to echo the emails:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($results); $row++){
    for($col = 0; $col < count($results[$row]); $col++){
         foreach($results[$row][$col]->result() as $user){
               echo "<p>".$user->email."</p>";
         }
    }
}
```

I am using the CodeIgniter framework if that would help. I looked up array_diff() function and array_unique() but array_unique() won't take a 2 dimensional array or at least the documentation says it isn't designed for that. any suggestions?

each $results[$row] is unique in itself but the issue is that one $row might have the same email address as another and I don't want that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you generating your list of email addresses? From a database query?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is (*if you have only email address to compare*) is to compose one-dim array where `key` will represent the `original key` (*key of array with that email address*) and `value` is the `email address` itself.

Than, apply `array_unique()` to this *one-dimensional* array and afterwards parse this array back into *multi-dimensional* array of required structure using only keys that left after unification of array.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting you list of emails from a database, add `distinct` to your query as such:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT email FROM emailTable"; //Add other fields to select as needed

// Add this piece to order them. Not sure if you'd need it or not
$query .= " ORDER BY email ASC";

$result = query_db($query);
```

Then you know each `$row` is unique in your `$result` array

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
$existing_emails = array();
for ($row = 0; $row < count($results); $row++){
    for($col = 0; $col < count($results[$row]); $col++){
        foreach($results[$row][$col]->result() as $user){
            if( ! isset( $existing_emails[ $user->email ] ) ) {
                $existing_emails[ $user->email ] = 1;
                echo "<p>".$user->email."</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We'll keep an associative array to remember the e-mails we've processed so far so we don't send anything to them again.

Comment: If he's emailing this list of people, we probably want to keep the results in an easy access array still. I suppose we can look at the keys of `$existing_array`, but it may be easier to set the key to a counter and set the array's value to the email.

Comment: Thank you! that worked great! but as Douglas A. Crosby, I am going to need to email then and an easy access would be nice.... would I have to do a foreach to get those out?

Comment: Okay what i did to change that was instead of storing the value of 1 into the $existing_emails[$user->email] i did the following: 
$existing_emails[$user->email] = $user->email so that when i go through a foreach loop i can grab and email them only once. THANKS AGAIN everyone!

Comment: If you found the answer correct or useful, upvote and mark as answered! Thanks!